# Ansible Playbook error handling between Plays

Tags: ansible

I am using a playbook to achieve the following:

- Connect localhost to a remote network via OpenVPN
- Install a software package to a remote host in the remote network
- Disconnect localhost from the OpenVPN connection

It is noteworthy that the first and last step have to be run on localhost to be able to (dis-)connect OpenVPN.

When there is any error in play #2 (software installation), the play aborts as per default. 
However, this in turn aborts the playbook's execution completely and the OpenVPN connection is left intact, which is not desired.

I already searched [the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html) for error handling, but they don't specify any way of rescuing on "play level" and continuing with the next play in the playbook.

I can't use `block` with `rescue` because this method is constrained to the currently running play.

My playbook is as follows:

```
- name:                   Connect to OpenVPN-Server
  hosts:                  localhost
  roles:
    - role:               ovpn-connect
      when:               HOSTING_TYPE == 'openvpn'


- name:                   'Setup {{ PRODUCT }} server on {{ HOSTNAME }}'  
  hosts:                  '{{ HOSTNAME }}'
  gather_facts:           no
  roles:    
  - role:                 docker

  - role:                 certbot
    when:                 SSL == 'yes'

  - role:                 {{ PRODUCT }}

  - role:                 seeding
    vars:
      INITIAL_USER:       admin
      INITIAL_PASS:       ***

  - role:                 restore
    when:                 FILENAME is defined and FILENAME != ''

  - role:                 zabbix-agent
    when:                 MONITORING is defined and MONITORING == 'yes'

- name:                   Disconnect from OpenVPN-Server
  hosts:                  localhost
  roles:
    - role:               ovpn-close
      when:               HOSTING_TYPE == 'openvpn'
```

Does any of you have an idea how i can overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try delegate_to like in example shown

```
- name: This is my play
  hosts: my-web-server

  tasks:
      - name: Disable pool member for upgrading
        bigip_pool_member:
          pool: foo
          name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
          state: disabled
        delegate_to: localhost

      - name: Upgrade the webserver
        apt:
          name: apache2
          state: latest

      - name: Re-enable pool member after upgrading
        bigip_pool_member:
          pool: foo
          name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
          state: enabled
        delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: AFAIK failed_when can only be set to roles and tasks, not entire plays.

Comment: Ok. now I got it.. you are using 3 plays because each play has different host (1, 3 in localhost, and 2nd play in remote host).. For this i would recommend you to use delegate_to. See my answer updated with example of delegate_to..